# Why does this code to reverse a number give "inf" as output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def reverse(num):
    b = 0
    while num > 0:
        b = b * 10 + num % 10
        num = num / 10
    return b

n = int(input("num: "))
print(reverse(n))
```

When a number is passed as argument, why does it give output as "inf"?

Comment: because you are multiplying 0 * 10  after your while loop

Comment: @Sri Nath, you need to use integer division. Use `num = num//10`

Comment: `num`  becomes negligible but still it will be added. `num` will be evaulated till `1*e^-323`

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

First look what is maximum number that you can "store" in float variable.

```
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

When you are iterating in while loop, you increase `b` and decrease `num`.
`b` is going bigger and bigger (see bottom, printing `b` in loop). Also in the same time `num` is going down, and reaches 0 at some point, which causes while loop (num is not >0) to break.

```
num is2
b=2, num=0.2
b=20.2, num=0.02
b=202.02, num=0.002
...
b=2.0202020202020194e+306, num=2.000000000000004e-307
b=2.0202020202020194e+307, num=2.0000000000000043e-308
b=inf, num=2.000000000000004e-309
b=inf, num=2e-310
...
b=inf, num=2e-322
b=inf, num=2e-323
b=inf, num=0.0
```

And when it reach maximum float value - `1.7976931348623157e+308` it becomes `inf`. After that few more iterations of while loop will occur. When `num` becomes so small (< 2e-323) that Python interpret is as 0, loop will end, because of not satisfy the while condition.

Answer (score 0):

`num / 10` does floating-point division. Therefore it takes quite an amount of iterations until `num` is 0 (mathematically speaking it will never become 0, but in practice it will eventually, due to limited numeric precision).

Therefore `b` becomes larger and larger in each iteration, until it is so large that there is no floating-point value that can represent it and it will become the special value `inf`.

You want to use integer division to split the number into digits:

```
num // 10
```